# ControlsFX SpreadsheetView: How to hide column?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, spreadsheet, controlsfx

May I ask how to hide/show a specific column in ControlsFX's SpreadsheetView. I do not want to totally remove it from Grid(GridBase). E.g. If I hide it, I can show it again without repopulating values.

Something like:

```
initial:
+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  |
+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  | 3  |
+----+----+----+


hide column 'B':
+----+----+
| A  | C  |
+----+----+
| 1  | 3  |
+----+----+


show column 'B': 
+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  |
+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  | 3  |
+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

As I responded to you in the ControlsFX google group, this feature is not possible right now as in ControlsFX 8.40.12.

However, I've made numbers of improvements in the SpreadsheetView including hiding rows/columns. The ability to sort the spreadsheetView. The ability to add some filters etc.

These functionalities are waiting to be merged into ControlsFX, if you want to try you can fork my repository : https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/pull-requests/627/new-features-for-the-spreadsheetview/diff#comment-None

Answer (score 0):

I have looked SpreadsheetColumn specs and it does not have hide or visible method. You can use a trick changing SpreadsheetColumn width size. I haved tried below approach and I think it is working. Can you try below approach? Sample code part:

```
        // This sample column:
        SpreadsheetColumn column = spreadsheetView.getColumns().get(1);
        double oriWidth = column.getWidth();
        columnHide = false;

        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                if(!columnHide){
                    column.setMaxWidth(0);
                    column.setMinWidth(0);
                    columnHide = true;
                }else{
                    column.setMinWidth(oriWidth);
                    columnHide = false;
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It hides but there are 2 problems with this approach: 1.Cell navigation focus - Doing TAB/SHIFT+TAB will focus on hidden column. Not sure if this is easy to tweak. 2. Column resize disabled - Can't drag the border handle in the column header to resize the column. Other columns are resizable though. I think this one is hard.

Comment: @Ezekiel Baniaga, Yes it has some issues. Why are you using the TableView instead of SpreadsheetView. I think this operations are easier with tableView? It has more sample and documentation. I would recommend you take a look.